# Subtract date objects?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr, calculated-columns

So I'm trying to simply subtract survey_date from child_date, but keep getting "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format" error. Both columns are in character format, so what's the problem?

This doesn't work:

```
df %>% mutate(child_age = survey_date-child_date)
```

> structure(list(case_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L,
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), person_id = c(1,  1, 1, 1, 1,
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), household_id = c(1,  1,
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), year = c(2018, 
>   2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
>   2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), month = c(1,  1, 1,
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), survey_date_cmc =
>   c(1417,  1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417,
>   1417,  1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417), mom_age =
>   c(28,  28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37,
>   37, 37, 37), mom_dob_cmc = c(1081, 1081, 1081, 1081, 1081, 1081, 
>   1081, 1081, 1081, 1081, 973, 973, 973, 973, 973, 973, 973, 973,  973,
>   973), name = c("b3_01", "b3_02", "b3_03", "b3_04", "b3_05",  "b3_06",
>   "b3_07", "b3_08", "b3_09", "b3_10", "b3_01", "b3_02",  "b3_03",
>   "b3_04", "b3_05", "b3_06", "b3_07", "b3_08", "b3_09",  "b3_10"), value
>   = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1297,  1297, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), child_date = c(NA, NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
>   NA, NA, "2008-01-01", "2008-01-01", NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
>   survey_date = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01",  "2018-01-01",
>   "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01",  "2018-01-01",
>   "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01",  "2018-01-01",
>   "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01",  "2018-01-01",
>   "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01")), class = c("grouped_df",  "tbl_df",
>   "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups =
>   structure(list(
>       mom_age = c(28, 37), case_id = 1:2, .rows = list(1:10, 11:20)), row.names = c(NA, 
>   -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))

[image: Data Frame]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns are `character` class.  It needs to be converted

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(child_age = as.Date(survey_date) - as.Date(child_date))
```

---

For better control with the `unit`s, can use `difftime`

```
df %>%
   mutate(child_age = difftime(as.Date(child_date), as.Date(survey_date), unit = 'weeks'))
```

Or using `interval` from `lubridate`

```
lubridate)
df %>% 
     mutate(child_age = interval( as.Date(child_date), as.Date(survey_date))/years(1))
```

Comment: @AMB1274 you can get that in day and divide by 365 or with 53 for weeks